# Local installation of Python 3.5 and pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install Python 3.5.4 on Fedora 26 without root permission locally. I did the following:

```
mkdir ~/python3p5      
cd ~/python3p5
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.4/Python-3.5.4.tgz
tar zxfv Python-3.5.4.tgz
find ~/python -type d | xargs chmod 0755
cd Python-3.5.4
```

Then I compiled the source following its guideline

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/python3p5
make && make install
```

Last few installation messages are

> Collecting setuptools
>
> Collecting pip
>
> Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
>
> Successfully installed pip-9.0.1 setuptools-28.8.0

.bashrc_profile has been updated as

```
export PATH=$HOME/python3p5/Python-3.5.4/:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/python3p5/Python-3.5.4
```

It seems pip has been installed as well. But I am not able to locate this executable. How can I also install pip locally and add packages to my locally installed python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your paths must be

```
export PATH=$HOME/python3p5/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/python3p5/lib
```

Please check these directories exist.

Comment: Thanks,this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If all your trying to do it install python onto fedora, there is a simpler method. See the link below.

https://www.tecmint.com/install-pip-in-linux/

Also, you could just use an IDE such as pycharm or eclipse to program in python.

Comment: I should add that I do not have root permissions and I am updating the description accordingly.